# Simple way to two-way-bind a DOM el and a JS obj

Tags: javascript, dom

What's the simplest (i.e. without extraneous functionality) way to ensure that the innerHTML of a DOM element is always the same as the value of a JS obj?

For example:

```
<h1>Yep</h1>

status = "Nope";
```

now it says "Nope".

---

Now the user turns on ContentEditable and edits the h1 to say "Yes!"...

```
(status == "Yes!";) #true
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use getters and setters:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elem') // an input for example

var obj = {
  _value: undefined,
  set value(value) {
    elem.value = this._value = value // bind value to input
  },
  get value() {
    return this._value  
  }
}

elem.addEventListener('input', function() {
  obj.value = this.value // bind input to value
})
```

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/yexife/1/edit